# How do I install wunderlist?

Tags: installation, wunderlist

[Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/) is a todo list, and apparently they now have Linux support. How do I install it?

Comment: The solution to make it work with 11.10 is here:
http://support.wunderlist.com/customer/portal/questions/63885-ubuntu-11-1-installation-?new=63885 And it works, indeed!

Comment: Unfortunately, they seem to have dropped their linux support for the native client. Too bad I've got a little bit late for the party...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

You can install Wunderlist via the Ubuntu Software Center. Open the Ubuntu Software Center, then search for `Wunderlist` - you can then install it from there. However, at time of writing, this will *not* work in 11.10, due to some incompatibility issues.

However, you can try the manual way outlined below.

First, download Wunderlist [from their website](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/).

Now, you need to unpack the `.tgz` that it comes in - run the following:

`tar  xvzf ./Downloads/wunderlist*.tgz`

Then you need to open the `Wunderlist` file - open up Nautilus (or your file browser of choice) and navigate to the `~/Wunderlist-<version number>` folder. In there you'll find a file named `Wunderlist` - double click it, and Wunderlist will open up - login and you're ready to go.

Comment: When I do this I get a window with license information and when I click run it crashes. I can only start the app by typing "sudo ./Wunderlist" I have Wunderlist-1.2.4 if that helps.

Comment: @Balthazar You should report that as a bug [here](http://support.wunderlist.com/)

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10 are here

[How To Install Wunderlist In Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04 Or 11.10 ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-wunderlist-in-ubuntu.html)

Edit Nov 2012:
Still no luck but you may use Fogger to get Wunderlist, web version, as a webapp in Ubuntu. Just install Fogger via Software Center, open Dash, enter 'Fogger' in it, 'create new' and follow the instructions. Courtesy of OMG Ubuntu!

[Fogger Brings To-Do App Wunderlist back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/fogger-brings-wunderlist-back-to-the-ubuntu-desktop)

Please note that in 12.10 you don't have to add any PPA's. Just follow my instructions above.

Comment: I've just installed Wunderlist as per instructions I linked to but it simply won't start. I get the welcome window (Wunderlist Installer) with Cancel and Run buttons. I press Run and it won't start. It's visible in Dash (program icon). Launching either from dash or by terminal command wunderlist or even by cd /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4 and then Wunderlist returns 'Wunderlist: command not found' error. Any hints?

Comment: I've added a post in the official wunderlist support section but so far no answers http://support.wunderlist.com/customer/en/portal/questions/342364-ubuntu-12-4-x64-linux-installation?new=342364

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know currently there is no official Wunderlist app for Linux. 
An alternative is wunderlistux which is basically a non official wunderlist app for linux

To install it you just have to download the last release from here:
https://github.com/edipox/wunderlistux/releases

You can use the AppImage which allows you to try the app without installing it but also allows you to install the app if you want. Or you can download the install script and run it as sudo:
`sudo ./install.sh`

More information can be found here: https://github.com/edipox/wunderlistux

Hope you like it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Perhaps you could expand this answer to explain how your wrapper will assist the OP in installing Wunderlist in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @ElderGeek ! I've updated my answer to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5
```

Comment: 'ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5': File exists'