# Why Wunderlist isn't available in the software center?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, wunderlist

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I tried to install Wunderlist form the software center but it isn't avalaible like in Natty, someone know why and how to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wunderlist does not support Ubuntu 11.10 just yet. The developers have been notified and we hope to see it updated for Ubuntu 11.10 soon!

Answer (score 3):

They do not have yet inserted it in 11.10 software center.

Here is a [guide on how to install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62300/how-do-i-install-wunderlist).