# Wunderlist 1.2.4 doesn't work even through terminal

Tags: wunderlist

I downloaded the tgz then unpacked it , double clicked the wunderlist icon but no response , I ran the terminal and wrote the command mentioned here 
[How do I install wunderlist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62300/how-do-i-install-wunderlist)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5
```

and it returned "ln " invalid option -- /"

I have Ubuntu 11.10

Thank you

Comment: Can you double-check that there are no spaces after / in your command anywhere? I.e. "/ usr" instead of "/usr"

Comment: no spaces mate :( thx

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here:

[Wunderlist | Portal](http://support.wunderlist.com/customer/portal/questions/63885-ubuntu-11-1-installation-?new=63885)

...and it works.